# Php Case Statement Query

Tags: php, mysql, select, drop-down-menu, case-statement

Hey I was wondering if this is even possible. I want to know if I can pull the information from a database and display if in a new table using a drop down menu. For example the user will log into the website, their information such as username will be stored in a session.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    header("location:index.php");
}
?>
```

As you can see above this is how im storing the username in the session. Next I want the user to be able to book an activity using a drop down menu system. The logic I have thought of is the following

```
<?php 
switch ($_GET['ActivityName']) 
{ 
case 'DeepseaDive': 
$sql = "SELECT Time,Day,Instructor,NumberAllowed,AdultPrice,JuniorPrice FROM Activity WHERE ActivityName = $activityname";
 $myData = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error($con)); 
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){...}
break; 

case 'Swim with Sharks': 
echo 'You chose B'; 
break; 
case 'Swim with Dolphins': 
echo 'You chose C'; 
break; 
case 'Aquariam Tour': 
echo 'You chose D; 
break; 
case 'Snorkeling': 
echo 'You chose E'; 
break; 
} 

?>
```

Comment: Is there sql injection "off-the-shelf"?

Comment: You have a brace where it either doesn't belong or is misplaced at the end of this line `$sql = "SELECT Time,Day,Instructor,NumberAllowed,AdultPrice,JuniorPrice FROM Activity WHERE ActivityName = $activityname $myData = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error($con)); while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){` <= brace mismatch for your `while` loop.

Comment: Plus this line `WHERE ActivityName = $activityname $myData = mysql_query($sql,$con)` that doesn't seem right. If anything, you'd need to wrap `ActivityName = $activityname` in quotes `ActivityName = '$activityname'`

Comment: @Fred-ii-, wrong... it's not sanitize this var...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean @vp_arth Look at OP's syntax highlighting.

Comment: Plus, why did you edit OP's code? @vp_arth Clearly there were errors. This is clearly invalid `WHERE ActivityName = $activityname`

Comment: I'm about your `'$activityname'` - what about `$activity = "' or '1"` ?

Comment: I don't know. OP's code is making my head spin @vp_arth I'm not going to go any further with this. I'll let someone else figure out this spaghetti code.

Comment: and see you redirect header? Is it IE specification?

Comment: user3346278, are you still here? You should learn a php syntax before dropdowns coding. Here is a good site: php.net

Comment: If you're going to "fix" the OP's code as you did in an edit, you left out the missing quote in `echo 'You chose D;` which should read as `echo 'You chose D';` @vp_arth Syntax highlighting is still off.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I think, that was a typo, but now I see, that it's general issue)) sorry for my edit)